# Is it OK to modify files while a "git push" is running

Tags: git

I know this is a silly question, and I think I know the answer. Just curious while waiting for a progress bar to reach 100% :)

Is it OK to modify the files while a "git push" is running?

I am doing a large push that has been running for a few minutes so far. I am just curious about what will happen if I start to modify the files being pushed at this point in time.

Comment: Yeah, it is. I didn't see that one before posting, but the answer to this is better IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "modify the working tree", the answer is nothing, because push is only operating on the commits you made.

If you mean "add new working tree modifications to the index", the answer is still nothing, for the same reason.

If you mean "add new commits", the answer is almost certainly nothing, because git uses lockfiles to prevent concurrent modification. Potentially if some platform lacks correct lockfile support something could go wrong with the last case, but I have no idea if any such platform exists that supports git.